# regex for htaccess redirect

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

Looking for a regex to redirect (remap) old URL to the Wordpress site efficiently.

The goal is to redirect all the old URL to a new set of URLs without losing the pagerank ( 301 redirect )

`/file/Abc_123_ABC_Abc.shtml` to be `/abc-123-abc-abc`

Objectives:

> 1.remove  /file/
>
> 2.convert to lowercase
>
> 3.replace all _ with - (appears about 2 to 4 times in a URL)
>
> 4.remove the extension (both .htm & .shtml)

How to achive the point 3 in htaccess redirect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost identical use-case (the only difference is the lowercase and the folder name):

[HTACCESS : RegEx match replace for URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068235/htaccess-regex-match-replace-for-url/6068347#6068347)

Best I'm aware, you cannot lowercase using a rewrite rule, so you'll need to rewrite to a redirect handler, and process it from there:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^file/(*+)\.html?$ /file/redirect.php [L,QSA]
```