# htaccess 301 redirect pattern needed

Tags: regex, .htaccess, http-status-code-301

I need to create a htaccess 301 redirect that redirect all

www.mydomain.dk/40005/ (Where 40005 can be any 5 digit number)
to
www.mydomain.dk

Anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068235/htaccess-regex-match-replace-for-url/6068347#6068347 and http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IT is simple :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^[0-9]{5}/?$ / [QSA,L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

In your document root's htaccess file, or in your vhost config:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/[0-9]{5}/?$ /
```

ALternatively, you can also use mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain\.dk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?[0-9]{5}/?$ / [L,R=301]
```