# Permanent Redirect huge number of url-s via .htaccess or php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I just had to make general changes and had to move all url-s from one php page to another. This caused over 64000 missing url from Google. How can i change the old url like:

www.website.com/shop.php?product=nokia-phones-s5
 to new url which is
www.website.com/store.php?product=nokia-phones-s5

The only difference is shop.php in url becomes store.php
What is better - php redirect and how or .htaccess redirect and how?

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTACCESS : RegEx match replace for URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068235/htaccess-regex-match-replace-for-url)

Comment: You may replace shop.php by store.php in all urls by one rule with "RedirectMatch" in your .htaccess, possible duplicate here.

Comment: Alex I don't think the suggested dublicate can be used in my case

Comment: And something else, not all url-s must be changed, only those requests that match shop.php in the url..

Comment: That's the purpose of the Redirect**Match** rule.

Comment: :) Alex , you probably understand that I can not take risk to experiment with things that I am not understanding, that's why I asked for help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your `/phones/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /phones/

RewriteRule ^shop\.php$ store.php [L,NC,NE,R=301]
```

Query string is automatically forwarded to new target.

Comment: tested and it doesnt redirect nothing, no errors but no redirects as well..what could be wrong?

Comment: You are entering URL as `www.website.com/shop.php?product=nokia-phones-s5` in browser and it didn't redirect? Are you sure .htaccess is enabled?

Comment: yes, both are YES, but I am not entering url, I am clicking on google WMT crawl errors urls page to test if this works..

Comment: why RewriteRule is ^shop\.php but not RewriteRule ^shop.php    ?

Comment: ok first test the rule by entering directly `www.website.com/shop.php?product=nokia-phones-s5` in the browser and see if that works. If that doesn't work either, verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting same garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not?

Comment: dot is special character in regex that matches anything so `shop.php` can also match `shop-php` OR `shopXphp` ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63622/discussion-between-europeuser-and-anubhava).

Comment: Actually it is not wrong, there was long discussion with OP on this.